# Harddisk space used by unknown data on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, disk-space

I'm really stuck on a problem with two of my drives (1 hdd + 1 ssd):
Both show they are almost full after I have cleaned (wiped) the free space of the drives using PartitionGuru. (that finished without any error)

According to recommendations from the forum I have checked the drives with WinDirStat and Treesize (both running with SYSTEM priviliges) with the following results:

The drive is a 120GB SSD (showing 111.8 GB in windows) with shadow copies etc. disabled
WinDirStat showing 78.5 GB of data, 31.7 GB of and 1.7 GB of free space
Tresize showing 78.5 GB of data and 1.7 GB of free space

My second drive (a 1 TB HDD) even shows several hundred GB as unknown.

I have tried all I could think of - but i couldn't access the "unknown" data. How can I get the free space back?

Thanks

Edit:

Disk Management:

[image]

Comment: "Several hundred GB as unknown" sounds to me like you've not partitioned the disk to utilise the full capacity of the disk(s)...

Comment: Windows shows aprox 960 GB for the drive (partition) as total capacity. It's just that I can only find 300 GB of data on the drive - even when running a tool like treesize with SYSTEM priviliges. But windows still says the drive is full = 960 GB used)

Comment: Can you post up a screenshot of your "Disk Management"

Comment: You can see a screenshot at:  
http://www.azcd.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/screen.jpg
the SSD drive is E:
the hdd D: is currently not visible due to checkdisk running deep analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running Chkdsk over the night for the d: drive. That one seems to be fixed.
So I guess that is the solution.

I ran the following command: chkdsk d: /r /f (for the d: drive)
(I ran it with SYSTEM priviliges)

Comment: the second drive was also "cleaned" with checkdisk successfully